Derivation of Compton wavelength in Tong's QFT notes
On page 2 of David Tong's notes on QFT: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html, he makes use of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle to describe relativistic effects for a particle of mass $m$ in a box of size $L$. In particular, he says that at distances shorter than $$\lambda = \frac{\hbar}{mc},$$ the uncertainty in energy exceeds the barrier to create particle anti-particle pairs.
The uncertainty principle states that $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2,$  but Tong writes $$\Delta p \geq \hbar/L.$$ Why the missing factor of 2? Is this just convention? He then states that the Compton wavelength is associated with the uncertainty in energy being $$\Delta E = 2 m c^2.$$ Again, why is there a factor of 2 here? The rest energy of a particle is $mc^2$ so wouldn't it be enough for the uncertainty in energy to exceed just $mc^2$ for there to be a possibility of creating the same particle out of vacuum? Finally, if we do use $2mc^2,$ we get the following constraint on the length of the box
$$\Delta E = 2 mc^2 \geq \hbar c/L$$ $$\implies L \geq \frac{1}{2}\hbar/mc,$$ which is half the Compton wavelength. This tells us that if the uncertainty in energy exceeds $2mc^2,$ then the uncertainty in the particle's position exceeds half the Compton wavelength.
Then shouldn't the correct statement be: for distances greater than half the Compton wavelength, particle anti-particle creation is possible?

The whole argument is a rough order of magnitude estimate, so no numeric factors are being kept.

What about the last comment which implies an inequality $L \geq \hbar/mc$ ? That seems to be telling us that relativistic effects imply distances greater than Compton length, rather than less than that Tong argues?
